# Create a dynamic "checkbox" query in Access for end users

Tags: database, ms-access

**Use-Case Scenario**

I have a client with low-income residents. These residents can fill out a paper form with a bunch of check boxes.

It has one section for "Education" (GED, diploma, associates, etc) and another for "Skills" (HVAC, plumbing, etc)

Employers reach out to my client, and for example ask for all their HVAC trained residents with a GED.

Right now, they manually comb through paper records looking for a match

**Solution So far**

I am setting them up with an access database.

We have short fields for name, cell, email, address, etc.

We then have yes/no boxes for the different skills that appear on the paper form.

I have built the table and a form that the clients employees can easily fill out once they receive the paper copy.

**My Issue I need your help with**

I would like to have a dynamic query that prompts the end user (my clients' employees) to simply check some boxes and spit out the Personal Information of the resident.

For example, they can tick "HVAC" and then tick "GED", hit a search button that starts the query against the yes/no boxes, and spits out the personal information of the residents that match the skills and education they checked.

I've built individual pre-made static queries for each individual skill, but it's clunky and isn't that user friendly.

I am very inexperienced when it comes to access, if you have training material (youtube video, how-to site) that covers this exact scenario, I can figure out with just that. I think my issue is, I don't know access terminology enough to properly search for what I'm wanting to find.

Comment: You need a form where users can select these criteria then use VBA code to build filter and apply to form or report. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. Your question is really too broad and not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple case, where you only want to filter by yes/no columns, you don't have to use VBA. It's more flexible (and perhaps efficient) though.

Create a search form (let's call it `frmSearch`), with unbound check boxes for all skills (`chkHVAC`, `chkGED` etc.)

Then you can use a single query that covers all skills, using boolean logic:

- If the check box is not checked (`chkHVAC = False`), this skill is not filtered (records are returned, whether the field is true or false).
- If it is checked, only records are returned that have the field = True.

Like this. `[HVAC]` and `[GED]` are the table columns.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (Forms!frmSearch!chkHVAC = False OR [HVAC] = True)
  AND (Forms!frmSearch!chkGED  = False OR [GED] = True)
  AND ... etc.
```

You can put a button on the search form, that opens the query (and perhaps closes it if it's already open):

```vb
DoCmd.Close acQuery, "myQuery"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myQuery
```

Comment: Cool beans! So (1) Create form, (2) checkboxes for all education and skills (3) then, based on the bits checks in the form, have a query using the logic you gave me, will know to only query the checked values. I'll see what I can do! I don't know how to build the query or how/where to do it, but I can figure that out. I'll let you know what happens! I appreciate you. I bountied all my points for this haha.

Comment: It's a static query, like the ones that you already built, but it covers all skills dynamically (depending on the checkboxes). You only need to edit it if you add a new skill.

Comment: working on it now! I had some emergency VPN's this week that have taken my attention away, apologies.

Comment: Actually having a weird issue. This could be an issue on my end. My form has checkboxes the end user fills out. The checkboxes have three possible values for some reason (I'm only expecting two?) and they're filled, checked, and empty.

If the checkbox is empty, the query prompts the user for text input. I need to troubleshoot my form I think

Comment: it runs successfully! Now I just have to figure out how to have it actually display results....I used the GUI for my static queries.

https://pastebin.com/twYYJjm3

Comment: For the checkboxes: set `TripleState=False`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.CheckBox.TripleState

Comment: Hey @andre, sorry to bring this back up. So I'm almost done with it, but something weird. I wasn't getting any results to spit out. I made a test entry where ALL skills were checked (=true) in the table, and all skills were unchecked in the search form (=false) and I was able to get a record to spit out then. This lines up with the `AND ( (form = false) OR (table=true) )` logic. Any ideas on how to get it to only show the ones that are checked? I've been racking my brain, we're almost there.

Comment: Actually @andre, doesn't matter what the form has, as long as every skills/education in the table is checked, the resident will show up.

Comment: See answer on your new question. @Ghawblin

Answer (score 1):

More explicitly:
we start with a table structure like:
[image]

Then we create a search form so the database users don't have to learn to use access.
[image]

Next, the users select some combination of skills and education levels from the form and hit the button triggering the button click event.
[image]

After clicking through some message boxes the user gets:
[image]
I couldn't get the code from the internet that was supposed to open up the query as a datasheet to work so I created and opened a temporary table.  I felt this was ok as this is the wrong approach anyway (more later).  here is the code behind the button click event which creates the sql string for each combination of selected education and skills:

```
Private Sub SearchForSkillsButton_Click()
'listboxes are better for this application.  do not have to add new checkboxes and code every time some client has a new skill.
Dim sqlstring As String
sqlstring = BuildBaseSQLStringandFilterBySkills
sqlstring = AddEducationLevelFilters(sqlstring)
OpenandDisplayTable sqlstring
End Sub

Public Function BuildBaseSQLStringandFilterBySkills() As String
Dim sqlquerystring As String
Dim item As Variant
sqlquerystring = "SELECT [Clients].[FirstName], [Clients].[LastName] INTO SearchResultsTable " & _
"FROM Skills INNER JOIN (EducationLevels INNER JOIN ((Clients INNER JOIN ClientEducation ON Clients.ClientsID = ClientEducation.ClientID) INNER JOIN ClientSkills ON Clients.ClientsID = ClientSkills.ClientID) ON EducationLevels.EducationID = ClientEducation.EducationLevelID) ON Skills.SkillID = ClientSkills.SkillsID"
Dim firstitem As Boolean
firstitem = True
For Each item In SelectMultipleSkillsListBox.ItemsSelected
If firstitem = True Then
firstitem = False
sqlquerystring = sqlquerystring & " Where ([Skills].[SkillID] = " & SelectMultipleSkillsListBox.ItemData(item)
Else
sqlquerystring = sqlquerystring & " AND [Skills].[SkillID] = " & SelectMultipleSkillsListBox.ItemData(item)
End If
Next item
BuildBaseSQLStringandFilterBySkills = sqlquerystring
End Function

Public Function AddEducationLevelFilters(filterstring As String) As String
If Me.CheckBoxGED = True Then
filterstring = filterstring & " AND [ClientEducation].[EducationLevelID] = 1 "
End If
If Me.CheckBoxHighSchool = True Then
filterstring = filterstring & " AND [ClientEducation].[EducationLevelID] = 2 "
End If
If Me.CheckBoxSomeCollege = True Then
filterstring = filterstring & " AND [ClientEducation].[EducationLevelID] = 2 "
End If
filterstring = filterstring & ")"
AddEducationLevelFilters = filterstring
End Function

Public Sub OpenandDisplayTable(sqlstring As String)
DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlstring)
DoCmd.OpenTable ("SearchResultsTable")
End Sub
```

Here is a link for a long tutorial about making access search forms:
http://www.iaccessworld.com/create-search-form-using-vba-ms-access/
normally you would also turn the query into a report which has the advantage of being printable:
https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/access2016/creating-reports/1/

Comment: sorry I was supposed to give an example of a more correctly designed search form but my access is bugging so hard I have to reinstall it.

Comment: I really appreciate the time and effort you put into this, thank you.