# ACCESS select is runing, insert does not work

Tags: vba, select, parameters, insert, popup

The select below runs well:

```
SELECT szurt.*, *
FROM szurt
WHERE (Forms!start!k1 = FALSE OR [text1] = TRUE)   
  AND (Forms!start!k2 = FALSE OR [text2] = TRUE);
```

when inserting where the condition does not work:

```
INSERT INTO int_alapfeladat ( fenntart_tipus, fenntart_megnev,
                            fenntart_kapcs, fenntart_elerhet, om )
SELECT [int_alapfeladat].[fenntart_tipus], [int_alapfeladat].[fenntart_megnev],
       [int_alapfeladat].[fenntart_kapcs], [int_alapfeladat].[fenntart_elerhet],
       [int_alapfeladat].[OM]
FROM szurt
WHERE (Forms!start!k1 = FALSE OR [text1] = TRUE) 
  AND (Forms!start!k2 = FALSE OR [text2] = TRUE);
```

Prompts for a parameter in a pop-up window, miért... help:( /it would be nice to help with some example code/ THX.!!

Comment: Are text1 and text2 in the table?

Comment: Yes,  fields in table . /from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59202421/create-a-dynamic-checkbox-query-in-access-for-end-users/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
    int_alapfeladat 
    ( fenntart_tipus, fenntart_megnev, fenntart_kapcs, fenntart_elerhet, om )
SELECT 
    [fenntart_tipus], [fenntart_megnev], [fenntart_kapcs], [fenntart_elerhet], [OM]
FROM 
    szurt
WHERE 
    (Forms!start!k1 = FALSE OR [text1] = TRUE) 
    AND 
    (Forms!start!k2 = FALSE OR [text2] = TRUE);
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes.. THX.!